# Why was the past tense used here? "I died an X"

Tags: tenses, past-tense

In 2023 movie, *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, this conversation took place when a character was dying:

> **Dying character**: (holding Scott's cheek) Thanks, Scott. You always were a brother to me.
>
> **Scott**: I was? (a few moments later) I was.
>
> **Dying character**: (coughs and exhales sharply) And at least I **died** an Avenger.
>
> **Scott**: Yeah. You did. Yeah. No, it’s… You’re in.

Why did he use the past tense while he was still alive?

Why didn't he say one of these sentences?

- I'll die an avenger.
- I die an avenger.
- I'm gonna die an avenger.
- I'm dying an avenger.

Comment: It might be that the phrase "he died an X" is so common (e.g. "he died a free man") that the speaker is following that pattern. I wouldn't expect normal grammar from someone who's dying.

Comment: "He died an X" is from a third person. But my question is from a first person.

Comment: @SnackExchange: He uses first person because he's talking about himself, not about someone else. But it's still following the same pattern.

Comment: I mean it makes sense if it is used by a third person, not a first person.

Comment: @SnackExchange: That's the point though - he is following the same pattern, even though it doesn't 100% make sense on a literal interpretation.

Comment: He's imagining the glory or honor that will outlive him.  Nobody would say "At least I died in my sleep." Though they might say "At least I will die [or I will have died] in my sleep" (that is, and not suffering).

Comment: Why did someone change the character's name to "dying character"? It was clear the character is dying without changing the name.

Comment: @SnackExchange It was to remove the spoilers from the question. While we don't have an official policy here about spoilers (since we don't usually get spoilers), I think the edit was good because it means that people can't accidentally be spoiled (again, since we don't usually get spoilers).

Comment: This is an interesting one. The sentence seems fine to this native English Speaker; I guess what's happening almost subconsciously is that as all the necessary things that need to happen to become dead, have happened, and as actual death is merely a matter of waiting a few moments, it's fair to refer to having "died" in a certain state, ie: being an avenger.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

He projects the context into the future, when this present moment will be past. He thinks of what people will think of him after he dies. Imagine he did die and now we are thinking of him:

> At least he *died* an Avenger.

Some grammarians will tell you that he could have said:

> At least I will have died an Avenger.

But this is a movie, and using the past in this case gives more dynamic to the thought. It's more in front of your eyes.

Comment: Also, using "I will have" makes the situation conditional.  Using the past tense unconditionally about something that is yet to happen makes a claim that it is more certain.

Comment: Future perfect tense makes a prediction conditional on current belief, and speakers and listeners are all aware of the implicit "if things go as predicted".  Standard use of past tense lacks that built in conditional clause; so using past tense in place of future perfect tense expresses an elimination of the "if things go as predicted" grammatically.  The grammatically "illegal" use of past tense is trying to express that here.

Comment: This answer and H W's answer offer two competing reasons. Which is right? Honestly both sound made-up to me, but either answer _could_ claim some support if there are other examples of English speakers ever having done this before. Some evidence, in other words, would be great.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it was just a shortened form of "I will have died...".

Answer (score 32):

It shows the viewer that he has completely accepted his fate. It's not just something that will happen, it is something that is already in the process of happening, and so much so that it may as well have already happened. Clever, poetic dialogue compared to just using the future tense and stating matter-of-factly that he is about to die.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the expression "dead man walking".